# Authentication and authorization using oauth or jwt

Tags: angularjs, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

Few questions here:

1. using oauth2.0 for authentication and authorization

or

2. Use only jwt for login purpose

I have a application where users can register with any email address. It could be a work mail address. My primary focus is to allow users to sign up using third party email providers such as google, facebook etc but I would also want to allow users to use work mail address(example: name@company.com)

Keeping the above scenario in my mind, I am confused about the implementation using front-end or backend like:

use spring/java to implement oauth or jwt?

or

use frontend framework such as angular to implement oauth or jwt?

I am going in cycles reading blogs and articles and messing my head and finally end up here to post a question.

Why would one choose oauth/jwt + angular compared to oauth/jwt + java? Is the former gives better performance than latter?. Why technology experts coming up with these new ways to confuse developers. Anyway, I have a front end view with html angular and bootstrap and backend as spring/grails. So please help in figuring out the right way choosing the implementation.

Comment: Have you checked out the spring security plugins for grails? There are implementations for Facebook, twitter too.  http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

Comment: @NickHammond Yes I had a look at spring security but I want to know what is difference between implementation of frond end(angular+oauth) security compared to backend(spring+oauth). There is no difference?

Comment: the basic difference is deployment. A front end solution requires a third party backend implementation, ie Facebook, with which you would connect to. Implementing your own backend gives you control over both sides, but also the added complexity of managing both.

Comment: @NickHammond I didn't get you when you said "A front end solution requires a third party backend implementation, ie Facebook". ?

Comment: with any solution, you will have a front end, which a user will interact with, and a backend which maintains the users and their credentials (userid, password, roles, etc). specifically i was referring to your front end using facebook's backend as the credential store.